# Push notification not working with FCM

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get push notifications using Firebase in my Android app. The problem is when the app is in the foreground, I receive the notification and `onMessageReceived()` is called, however when I am on the background, I don't receive any notification and the `onMessageRecieved` isn't called.

What am I doing wrong?

**Manifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".notifications.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.class**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("MessagingService", "onCreate Firebase Service");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e("MessagingService", "onMessageRecieved");

        String body     = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        ooVooSdkSampleShowApp application = (ooVooSdkSampleShowApp) getApplication();

        Intent intent = new Intent(application.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(application.getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application.getContext());

        b.setAutoCancel(false)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.image_calendar_red)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) application.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It was the problem with the way server response being handled by Firebase SDK. I was sending notification using "notification" field from the server side.

**Notification** = Just show Notification when the app is in foreground. This is the rule for Firebase SDK/ GCM SDK

**Data** = Show Notification when the app is in background. This is the rule for Firebase SDK/GCM SDK.

On server side, I have done it like this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
            notification: {
            data: {
                 title: message
             },
             to : '/topics/user_'+username
```

[Further Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37067866/1250107)

Answer (score 0):

For receiving the notification in the background you have to add this lines to your app launcher activity.
and see image for sending the data from firebase console. From the key we get the data.

```
   if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        Object title = getIntent().getExtras().get("title");
        Object message = getIntent().getExtras().get("message");


        String tit=title+"";
        String msg=message+"";

        if(!tit.equals("null") && !msg.equals("null")) {
            //add your code which you want to perform on notification receive
        }

    }
```

[image]